# How is virtual base classes stored?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

So I understand that if you have the diamond inheritance problem and you do virtual inheritance it creates only one of the base class however how exactly is this represented?

In the vtable is there a pointer to the base class and when one of the derived classes is constructed it looks to see if that pointer exists already and if not it creates it and makes it point to the base class?

Comment: [Mandatory reading](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html). Short answer: With magic.

Answer (score 1):

You start out right. Although implementation details can vary, in effect yes there's information in the vtable (or anyway in class metadata) sufficient to find the base class.

To your second part, AFAIK there's no "see if the pointer exists already" in any implementation. C++ makes the most-derived class responsible for constructing all virtual bases. So with a normal diamond inheritance involving `Root`, `Middle1`, `Middle2` and `MostDerived`, the code emitted to construct instances of `MostDerived` will:

- construct `Root` and set a vptr to point to a vtable for `MostDerived`
- construct `Middle1` and `Middle2`
- construct data members of `MostDerived`
- execute the body of the constructor of `MostDerived`

I say "a vptr" rather than "the vptr", because during the construction of `Middle1` the `Root` base class is available but any virtual functions of `Middle1` *don't* yet refer to overrides defined in `MostDerived`. It's up to the implementation to sort this out, you can experiment for yourself by looking at object sizes how many hidden pointers are used to do it and whether the number depends on whether `Middle1` has virtual functions.

Note that the usual code emitted to construct instances of `Middle1` will:

- construct `Root` and set a vptr to point to a vtable for `Middle1`
- construct data members of `Middle1`
- execute the body of the constructor of `Middle1`.

When we're constructing the `Middle1` base class subobject of `MostDerived`, we only want to do two of those steps, not all three. For this reason, you will probably find that the emitted code for a class with more than one constructor contains multiple constructors -- one for objects whose most-derived type is the class, and a separate one for base class subobjects whose type is the class.

Comment: Or sometimes an extra function parameter saying whether or not to construct virtual bases.

Comment: @aschepler: fair enough. Crucially the standard doesn't let you take pointers to constructors, so the implementation can play any tricks it likes with calling conventions, multiple entry points or extra parameters. Falling through from the virtual base code to the rest of the normal constructor is an obvious ploy.